# Is a longer antanna better for reception ? Or just more directional?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

Let's say I have two antennas, A1 and A2, and they have identical radiation profiles. So the relative radiated energy in a given direction is the same for both antennas.

Let's assume also that we have a fixed signal source S.

Now the question :

Is it possible that A1 picks up more from signal S than A2 ? In other words, the Signal to Noise ratio delivered to the receiver circuit from A1 will be larger than A2 ? Is it possible to build two such antennas that while their radiation profile is the same, they still pick up different amount from the same signal source ?

Let's also assume that the two antennas are built from the same material, say copper.

For the sake of practicality, let's also assume that the source S emits radiation at 433MHz (70cm) frequency (an ISM band) because x-rays are also electromagnetic radiations but its not so easy to build radio equipment that utilizes them :)

**Let me put this question in different form :**

Say I have two antennas A1 and A2 (not the same as above), and two sources S1 and S2.

A1 is directed to S1 and A2 is directed to S2 such that A1 gives output power P to the receiving circuit if S1 is radiating and A2 gives the same output power P if S2 is radiating.

Now the question : can I combine A1 and A2 into a combined antenna CA, which outputs a power P to the receiving circuit if either S1 or S2 is radiating ? My feeling is that it is not possible because when S1 is radiating and CA picks S1's up then CA also radiates outwards towards S2, so CA's output power will not be P if only S1 or S2 is radiating.

Comment: You might consider moving this to the Ham SE site.

Comment: Well, perhaps, but maybe this is more like a physics/electromagnetism question. The question is, what characterizes an antenna ? Is an antenna uniquely characterized by only its radiation pattern? In other words, is the radiation pattern the only "dimension" by which two antennas can be distinguished ?

Answer (score 1):

Another important issue is impedance matching between the output of the antenna and the receiver input. The length being a full, half or quarter wavelength creates a resonance situation that helps to increase the sensitivity. 
But then the situation is less favorable if the received frequency deviates from a resonance frequency. For that reason designers of TV and FM antennas make them somewhat broadband. Obviously there is some trade-off.

For the medium and long wave broadcast ranges the above is no longer practible. There the recipy used to be the longer the better. But ferrite rod antennas are tuned to the receiving frequency, again a resonance situation.

As to your question matters also depend on the relative distance of the antennas. In case they are close to each other they will interact even without being connected through the receiver input. But I seem to remember that circuits exist that are able to combine the two signals in a constructive way. You might find more about this in publications of the ARRL

Answer (score 0):

Antenna sensitivity for a fixed length depends on the wavelength of receiving radiation. Antennas are usually designed having a length of half or full wavelength or even quarter.